# Compilation error using AltiVec SIMD vector type in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, simd, powerpc, altivec

Following is the code:

```cpp
int add = foo;
vector signed int v_add;
v_add[0] = add;
```

The error is: `error: invalid types 'vector int[int]' for array subscript`

Problem stays when I try  `add = v_add[0];`

Please explain the cause of this problem. I am using gnu version 3.3.2

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
$ cat vec.cpp
#include <altivec.h>
void foo () {
  int add = 1;
  vector signed int v_add;
  v_add[0] = add;
}
$ g++ -c vec.cpp
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)
```

Comment: OP is using a much older gcc toolchain (3.3.2) which I suspect didn’t support array syntax for AltiVec types.

Answer (score 1):

You can't treat AltiVec types like `vector signed int` as if they are arrays. Use e.g. the `vec_ld` intrinsic to load values from an array to an AltiVec vector.

Comment: If they're defined in terms of GNU C native vector extensions then you can in GNU C, and it could even be useful if element indexing uses an element type you want. (Which is presumably the case here since the vector declaration comes with signed int). https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html.  I assume it's at least as inefficient on x86, though, to shuffle / blend a scalar into an element of a vector, so convenient syntax is a performance trap if you aren't careful to avoid needing it much.

Comment: OP is using gcc 3.3.2, which is pretty old, and although gcc had AltiVec intrinsics support from 2.95 onwards, I think the vector extensions referred to came later.

Comment: That GCC version is insanely old and they should upgrade it.  Also, is a vector load really a useful answer here?  It's not even something you'd do as part of an element insert, is it?  (Store-forwarding stalls are bad on some PowerPC, right, so vector store / scalar store / reload sucks vs. shuffle and/or blend?)  Are you thinking that they maybe don't know how to get started, and were planning to use this to set all 4 elements separately, based on the fact that they didn't init the vector before doing this?  They didn't init the `int` either so IDK if that's significant.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming the OP was just getting started and didn't know how to load or initialise a vector. For initialisation there is unfortunately more than one syntax (gcc does it one way, while other compilers stick to the AltiVec spec) so I avoided that discussion and just mentioned a load intrinsic.